# A discrepancy in a vector identity involving gradient of product of 2 vectors.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

We know that:

$\nabla (Α\cdotΒ)=Α\times (\nabla \times Β)+Β\times (\nabla \times Α)+(Α\cdot\nabla )Β+(Β\cdot\nabla )Α$

Where $A$ and $B$ are two vectors.

Now, suppose that the curl and divergence of vector $A$ equals to zero. That is- $\nabla\times A=0$ and $A\cdot\nabla=0$. Also, let $\nabla\times B = 0$ and $B\cdot\nabla=n$, where $n$ is a positive number.

This means that vector $A$ does not changes with direction, while vector $B$ has only some positive divergence but no curl.

So, our original identity becomes:
$\nabla (Α\cdotΒ)=(Β\cdot\nabla )Α$

We now notice that $\nabla (Α\cdotΒ)$, a vector, has its direction in the direction of vector $A$. It is counter intuitive to me because it is $B$ which is changing, not $A$.

So, my question is- is the last equation correct? Will the direction of $\nabla (Α\cdotΒ)$ be in the direction of $A$, in the conditions I have previously described? Or I am interpreting something wrongly?

Comment: you suposse $A\cdot\nabla=0$, that is true if $A=0$

Comment: $\nabla \cdot A \neq A \cdot  \nabla$. The first is the divergence, the second is the directional derivative.

Comment: Note that the gradient of a function (in your case $\nabla(A\cdot B)$) points in the direction of the _greatest change_ of the function.

Comment: @Aurey, I was not aware of that. I think that is where i did wrong. I will check some textbooks to clarify my misconception and update. Thanks everyone!